# Spring Security Webflux CORS not disabled despite providing cors mapping in WebFlux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am using http basic authentication with Spring Security and WebFlux.
Despite disabling cors and adding cors mapping by creating a class that implements WebFluxConfigurer to add cors mapping, I am still not being able to send any request by my Angular application.
I have added two configuration files for security and the code is as following:
For configuring security in general

```java
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http){
        return http
                .cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager(ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService,
                                                               PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder){
        UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager manager = new UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager(userDetailsService);
        manager.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return manager;
    }
    @Bean
    public ReactiveAuthenticationManager reactiveAuthenticationManager(ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService,
                                                               PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        return authentication ->
            userDetailsService.findByUsername(authentication.getPrincipal().toString())
                    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.empty())
                    .flatMap(user -> {
                        final String username = authentication.getPrincipal().toString();
                        final CharSequence rawPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
                        if (passwordEncoder.matches(rawPassword, user.getPassword())) {
                            System.out.println("User has been authentication " + username);
                            return Mono.just(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities()));
                        }
                        return Mono.just(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, authentication.getAuthorities()));
                    });

    }
        @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder noPasswordEncoder(){
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

For configuring CORS:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class WebConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("localhost:4200")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                .allowedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Authorization", "Content-Type");
    }
}
```

The error message:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/course/my-courses' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: 'error', …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/course/available: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "http://localhost:8080/course/available"
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Please show what the console tab error message is in the browser.

Comment: Here is the error message:
```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/course/my-courses' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: `localhost:4200` is not the same as `http://localhost:4200`

Comment: I edited the the allowedOrigins from ```localhost:4200``` to ```http://localhost:4200``` and it is still not working.

Comment: well then you need to check, in the browser network if you actually have a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set if you don't then your configuration is not loadad. If its not loaded then you need to check why it is not loaded, what your package structure looks like can spring find your config etc. I can see you have straight off copy pasted the code from Baeldung, but they are often outdated, the official docs have a different approach to adding a CORS config https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/cors.html

Comment: if none of that works, then you have to provide a small reproducible example

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Spring Security you should configure CORS for Spring Security.

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http){
        return http
                .cors(cors -> cors
                         .configurationSources(corsConfigurationSource()))
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .build();
    }


    private CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT",
                                       "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 
                                       "Authorization", "Content-Type"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

Or if you want share the Spring MVC's CORS configuration you should configure Spring Security CORS with defaults

```java
     .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
```

Spring Doc references:

[Reactive Security CORS](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/integrations/cors.html)

[Spring Security and Spring MVC CORS sharing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.4.RELEASE/reference/html5/#cors)